# How to make selector switch work after selecting another option?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a selector with 4 options: 1 is default and is not included in the later used `switch`.
When I select another value (in my case "1" because I included it in the `switch`) nothing happens. But if I leave the option with `value="1"` as the default option, the switch works and displays my text.

HTML:

```
<select id="select-forma">
        <option value="11">-Alegeti Forma-</option>
        <option value="1">Forma 1</option>
        <option value="2">Forma 2</option>
        <option value="3">Forma 3</option>

 </select><br>
 <h1 id="mp">Aveti nevoie de <span id="mpv">100</span> m2 folie</h1><br>
```

jQuery:

```
switch(parseInt(document.getElementById('select-forma').value)){
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('mp').style.display = 'block';
      break;
```

How can I make the switch work properly?

EDIT: Solved it myself by putting the `switch` in a function and using `onchange = "function()"` for the selector

Answer (score 0):

Awesome that your code works now, but I have a suggestion. You're using jQuery, which should enable you to make your code a little more consise.

In your switch, evaluate the returned value of `$(this).val()` instead of whatever you put in there. `$(this)` will refer to the jQuery object you're applying the `change` event on. Then, instead of assigning `block` to the css `display` property with the long vanilla JS line, use `.show()` like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#select-forma").change(function() {
    switch($(this).val()) {
      case 1:
        $("#mp").show();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```